# Slide UIInputView with UIViewController like Slack

Tags: ios, first-responder, inputview, inputaccessoryview

I'd like to use the UIViewController's input accessory view like this:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {
    return self.bar
}
```

but the issue is that I have a drawer like view and when I slide the view open, the input view stays on the window. How can I keep the input view on the center view like Slack does it.

[image]

Where my input view stays at the bottom, taking up the full screen (the red is the input view in the image below):

[image]

Comment: If slack's view slides over, then they're probably not setting it as the `inputAccessoryView`. They're probably just managing its location “manually” in code.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But if you use Slack, bring the keyboard up and slide down on the table view, the keyboard will start going down once you hit the top of the input view.  That makes me think it is an input view and is not being managed manually.

Comment: Doesn't that just indicate that they set `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag` or `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive`?

Comment: Yeah, they do that too, but because I'm managing my 'inputView' manually and the keyboard does not slide down once I reach the very top of my input view.  It slides down once I reach the top of the keyboard. Slack's acts like a real input view because the keyboard starts sliding down as soon as I hit the top of the input view.

Comment: I actually think they grab the frame of the keyboard and change that rather than using UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive. https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/blob/c49e2b80ecd52737f5c43cd831f47d74558ffa0a/Source/SLKInputAccessoryView.m

Comment: That solves my issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this exactly like Slack doing it, [Meiwin](https://medium.com/@meiwin) has a medium post here [A Stickler for Details: Implementing Sticky Input Field in iOS](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/a-stickler-for-details-implementing-sticky-input-fields-in-ios-f88553d36dab) to show how he managed to do this which he actually puts an empty `UIView` as an `inputAccessoryView` then track it’s coordinates on screen to know where to put his custom view in relation with the empty view, this way can be helpful if you are going to support `SplitViewController` on iPad, but if you are not interested in this way, you can see how I managed to do this like this image

**Here is before swiping**
[image]

**Here is after**
[image]

All I did was actually taking a snapshot from the `inputAccessoryView` window and putting it on the `NavigationController` of the `TableViewController`

I am using [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) from [Jon Kent](https://github.com/jonkykong) and it’s pretty easy to do it with the `UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate`

```
var isInputAccessoryViewEnabled = true {
    didSet {
        self.inputAccessoryView?.isHidden = !self.isInputAccessoryViewEnabled
        if self.isInputAccessoryViewEnabled {self.becomeFirstResponder()}
    }
}

func sideMenuWillAppear(menu: UISideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
    let inputWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.className == "UITextEffectsWindow"}).first
    self.inputAccessoryViewSnapShot = inputWindow?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
    if let snapShotView = self.inputAccessoryViewSnapShot, let navView = self.navigationController?.view {
        navView.addSubview(snapShotView)
    }

    self.isInputAccessoryViewEnabled = false
}

func sideMenuDidDisappear(menu: UISideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
    self.inputAccessoryViewSnapShot?.removeFromSuperview()        
    self.isInputAccessoryViewEnabled = true
}
```

I hope that helps :)