# inputAccessoryView slides while using a custom UINavigationController transition

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I'm using a custom navigation controller transition and when I'm pushing a new View Controller, my inputAccessoryView starts to slide up from bottom while transitioning (and not currently on the pushing view)..

The images for refference are the same as from this question:

[Slide UIInputView with UIViewController like Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326649/slide-uiinputview-with-uiviewcontroller-like-slack)

Answer (score 0):

If your custom accessory view is sliding up from the bottom with the keyboard then this is due to a textfield becoming the first responder. I would check that none of you text entry views are becoming the first responder, you can also use:

```
func endEditing(_ force: Bool) -> Bool
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting)

> **Discussion**
>
> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign.

If you do not get a result using this, I would look at how you create your input accessory view and where is it in the view controller's hierarchy, you could also change the view's alpha to 0 for the duration of the transition.